# Do with Plot command

Tags: plotting

In William T. Shaw's Complex Analysis with Mathematica textbook, written for Mathematica 5, he has this command in his exercises:

```
Do[Plot[x^2 + c, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}], {c, -1, 1, 0.2}]
```

But it does not work in Mathematica 11.1.0. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: In V6 they changed the default behavior for printing. I think wrapping a Print around the Plot might work for you Do[Print[Plot[x^2+c, {x,-2,2}, PlotRange->{-1,3}]], {c,-1,1,0.2}]

Comment: I can confirm that Bill's suggestion works.

Comment: `Column @ Table[Plot[x^2 + c, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}], {c, -1, 1, 1}]` also works and puts the output in a single cell.

Comment: In v5 and earlier, `Graphics` expressions did not automatically render as the graphics they represented.  Rendering was explicitly triggered with `Show`.  `Show` worked a bit like `Print`: it inserted a new cell in the notebook with rendered graphics. Plotting functions (but not `Graphics`) invoked `Show` automatically.  This is why the `Do` loop you quote had the side effect of rendering graphics.  Now you know why a function for *combining* (and not showing) graphics is called `Show`.  It's because in the past that's what it did: it showed the picture.

Comment: Take a look at [Plot functions do not print output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124077/5478) in common pitfalls thread.